# How to decide for the number of decimals for rounding

Tags: probability, statistics, logarithms

I am computing some **logarithms** and have a problem for the result's presentation. These are my numbers.

- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 0.0,
- 0.8109302162163288,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 0.4054651081081644,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 0.0,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098,
- 1.0986122886681098

With the standard deviation 0.37440091166480144

Showing the complete precision is too much, it would not help to understand the actual context. So where do I round? To two decimal places, four? Is there a rule of thumb? Can the standard deviation help here?

The input was: $\log(3/1)$, $\log(3/2)$, $\log(3/3)$ and $2 \cdot \log(3/1)$, $2 \cdot \log(3/2)$, $2 \cdot \log(3/3)$

Comment: Are your numbers supposed to be the logarithm of the same number?

Comment: @Eckhard No, different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would present either 2 or 3 places behind the decimal point, but that is more a matter of taste.  3 gives better the impression that the numbers that look equal really are equal.  It is a matter of taste.